# How can I convert c++ template code to equivalent C code

Tags: c++, c

I am new to programming in C.
I am trying to write below c++ template code in C language using macro.

```
template <typename MyType>
constexpr void copy_elem(MyType* src, MyType* dst) {
  auto type_size = sizeof(MyType);
  memcpy(dst, src, type_size);
}
```

How can I do this?

Edit:
Below code for macro worked for me

```
# define COPY_ELEM(SRC, DEST) {\
memcpy(DEST, SRC, typeof(sizeof(*SRC)));}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, why would you want to do such a thing?  If `MyType` is non-trivial, this code will likely cause problems.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with the template. `sizeof(type_size)` will always be the `sizeof size_t`. Are you trying to copy 1 element of en array or the entire array.

Comment: Step 1: Understand the visible behaviour of the template code. Step 2: Re-implement the behaviour in C, using C's idioms and best practices. Step 3: Exhaustively test the C++ implementation against the C implementation to ensure they have identical behaviour.

Comment: Templated programming is one of the major differences between C and C++, kind of the one of the reasons to introduce C++. Any attempt to convert it to C is most likely a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem So please elaborate **why** you are attempting to do this? Also please state whether this is the last of your problems in converting a larger project. If it is not, i.e. if it is the first  non-trivial problem, then I believe, as cynical as this may seem, that this is the point where giving up is your best option.

Comment: My previous comment practically agrees with the one by user4581301: convert on a much hihger level of abstraction. @user4581301 If you turn that into an answer I will consider it a helpful one.

Comment: In addition to the point raised by @PaulBaxter , this code will fail horribly if used on complex objects. And to be frank, they don't have to be that complex. One owned pointer and it's game over. Not a problem In C, but likely fatal in C++.

Comment: I just want to write a macro to copy value of any user defined type

Comment: The template code is actually incorrect, since the third argument of `memcpy()` should be `type_size`, not `sizeof(type_size)`.   If the latter worked, you just got lucky (or you only tested it on types of the same size as a `size_t`).    Even correcting for that, the macro you show is not equivalent - the macro is not type safe, and can be applied even if the types are incorrect.  Using `memcpy()` is actually a code smell - a detectable sign of code that will probably malfunction, for example due to undefined behaviour  - in C++.

Comment: @Yunnosch I leave that as a comment because it's pretty much a useless answer. It's 100% true, but of no use to the asker and minimal use to those who follow.

Answer (score 0):

`C` does not have templates in the sense of `C++`.`memcpy(dest, src, sizeof *src)` is a very ideomatic and self-documenting. However, one *can* do it in the pre-processor.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */

struct Foo { char letter; int number; };

struct Bar { unsigned id; char widget[4]; };

#define MYTYPE_NAME foo
#define MYTYPE_TYPE struct Foo
#include "copy.h"

#define MYTYPE_NAME bar
#define MYTYPE_TYPE struct Bar
#include "copy.h"

int main(void) {
    struct Foo foo_a = { 'a', 42 }, foo_b;
    struct Bar bar_a = { 7, "bar" }, bar_b;
    foo_copy_elem(&foo_a, &foo_b);
    bar_copy_elem(&bar_a, &bar_b);
    printf("foo_a { %c, %d }, foo_b { %c, %d }.\n",
        foo_a.letter, foo_a.number, foo_b.letter, foo_b.number);
    printf("bar_a { %u, %s }, bar_b { %u, %s }.\n",
        bar_a.id, bar_a.widget, bar_b.id, bar_b.widget);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In `copy.h`,

```
#include <string.h> /* memcpy */

#if !defined(MYTYPE_NAME) || !defined(MYTYPE_TYPE)
#error Name MYTYPE_NAME or tag type MYTYPE_TYPE undefined.
#endif

/* <Kernighan and Ritchie, 1988, p. 231>. */
#if defined(T_) || defined(CAT) || defined(CAT_)
#error Unexpected T_ or CAT_?.
#endif
#define CAT_(x, y) x ## _ ## y
#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define T_(thing) CAT(MYTYPE_NAME, thing)

typedef MYTYPE_TYPE T_(Type);

static void T_(copy_elem)(T_(Type) *const src, T_(Type) *const dst)
    { memcpy(dst, src, sizeof *src); }

#undef T_
#undef CAT_
#undef CAT
#undef MYTYPE_NAME
#undef MYTYPE_TYPE
```

This is a technique stemmed from [X-Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro). It doesn't make sense to introduce all this complexity for `memcpy`, but for larger blocks of code that have many steps or functions, it's one technique to avoid code re-use that is similar to templates.

Comment: Note that a refined method of X-macros makes do without the need to use `#undef`; which is relevant because some coding guides (e.g. extremely large development communities or commercial projects) forbid using it.